# Node.js downloading files - not all requests resolve, Promise.all doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, request

I'm trying to write an program in Node.js using request, fs-extra and promises to download an array of files that are served on Amazon S3.

With smaller files, the program works.  But with five or more larger files, at least one of the files doesn't download, and therefore the Promise.all never fires, so no console.log('Promise Finished: ', values);

Currently it downloads most of the files (complete) but the last one or two files are partial.  No errors get to console.

---

```
var urls = ['http://www.amazons3.com/10mb.mp4',
    'http://www.amazons3.com/20mb.mp4', 'http://www.amazons3.com/15mb.mp4', 'http://www.amazons3.com/19mb.mp4', 'http://www.amazons3.com/18mb.mp4', , 'http://www.amazons3.com/20mb.mp4'];

var promises = urls.map(url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var r = request(url)
    .on('response', (resp) => {
      if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Started: ', url);
        r.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('files/' + fileName))

        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err)
          reject(err)
        })
        .on('finish', function () {
          console.log('Downloaded: ', url);
          resolve(url);
        });
      } else {
          console.log(`${resp.statusCode} error for`, url);
          reject(`${resp.statusCode} error for ${url}`)
      }
    }).on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    });
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('Promise Finished: ', values);
});
```

I'm wondering if there are too many requests happening concurrently and that's why same files are failing to download?  If so how do I get around this?

My desired outcome is to completely download each file and fire the Promise.all and to be able to capture any errors that are occurring.  Additionally, it needs to be performant on bad connections.

**Update:** Found this issue on GitHub which may explain why the errors aren't firing in my scenario. https://github.com/request/request/issues/2161

Comment: Where does `r` come from in `r.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('files/' + url))`?   If `urls.length` is only 6 as you show, then that's not too many to run in parallel.  There are probably issues with using an url as a filename in the file system.  Also, you are missing error handling in a number of places such as on `r.pipe()` so if you get an error there, you will never resolve or reject your promise.

Comment: If some of these files don't complete, then there's an error somewhere and you just need to make sure you're logging all possible errors and they will then likely tell you what went wrong.  None of the infrastructure code you're using will silently swallow errors so you just have to make sure you're listening for and logging all possible errors.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00.  I've updated the code in the question to listen for errors on the pipe and will look for other places to log errors.

Comment: After some more testing, it looks like I might be facing a network issue.  I tried the code on a different network interface (wired Thunderbolt connection) and the same code never failed.

I still need to find an error point to be able to handle the error, so I'm going to go work on that.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use `reject` accordingly

```
var promises = urls.map(url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var r = request.get(url)
    .on('response', (resp) => {
      if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Started: ', url);
        r.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('files/' + url))
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err)
          reject(err)
        })
        .on('finish', function () {
          console.log('Downloaded: ', url);
          resolve(url);
        });
      } else {
          console.log(`${resp.statusCode} error for`, url);
          reject(`${resp.statusCode} error for ${url}`)
      }
    }).on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I've added your suggestions to my code.  While it doesn't fix the issue I'm having (or display any errors to give insight) I agree it improves the code.

Comment: you need to use `request.get` to get a `response event`. So, there was no event and the promise were never getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answer; you have to reject. But when you reject that means that any request that succeeded is lost (depending on how you continue your process).

You may not want this and can instead resolve with a special value so you can figure out what to do with the succeeded and failed requests:

```
function Fail(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = x=>(x&&x.constructor)===Fail;
const isNotFail = x=>!isFail(x);

var promises = urls.map(url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //same as Akash
  })
  .catch(err=>new Fail([err,url]));
});

Promise.all(promises)
.then(
  results=>{
    const successes = results.filter(isNotFail);
    const failed = results.filter(isFail);
    if(failed.length!==0){
      console.log("Some url(s) failed:");
      console.log(failed.map(([err,url])=>url));
      console.log("Errors:");
      console.log(failed.map(([err,url])=>err));
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion, and I might just use that.  I just tried to implement this and the outcome is the same - still no errors.  Can you see anywhere else I'm failing to reject?

Comment: @MikeJenkins Try the code 2 urls and post the output in your question. I can't see any problem with the code but not sure what the code is you are currently using. You should also log the error if Promise.all fails: `Promise.all().then().catch(err=>console.warn("something wrong:",err)`.  After Promise.all there is a `if(err)` That should throw an error because err is not defined, Remove that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what I'm experiencing is a symptom of this bug: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2161